Is there a ready solution to quickly extract the contents of pipenv `Pipfile.lock` to a Python dictionary?
The contents of the pipenv Pipfile.lock file looks like a nested Python dictionary.
Is there a ready solution (function/class/module) to quickly extract the contents of Pipfile.lock to a Python dictionary?
I tried:
content = []
with open(Pipfilelock) as f:
    for row in f:
        content.append(row.strip())
parsed_content = ' '.join(content).replace('true', 'True')
print(f"{parsed_content=}")

and obtained :
parsed_content='{ "_meta": { "hash": { "sha256": "0ed7c1ed593ef7fb644e2faa43e07f28a3c7d297b3b7da70b3a08807a4638fae" }, "pipfile-spec": 6, "requires": { "python_full_version": "3.10.12", "python_version": "3.10" }, "sources": [ { "name": "pypi", "url": "https://pypi.org/simple", "verify_ssl": True } ] }, "default": { "numpy": { "hashes": [ "sha256:03a8c78d01d9781b28a6989f6fa1bb2c4f2d51201cf99d3dd875df6fbd96b23b", "sha256:08beddf13648eb95f8d867350f6a018a4be2e5ad54c8d8caed89ebca558b2818", "sha256:1af303d6b2210eb850fcf03064d364652b7120803a0b872f5211f5234b399f20", "sha256:1dda2e7b4ec9dd512f84935c5f126c8bd8b9f2fc001e9f54af255e8c5f16b0e0", "sha256:2a02aba9ed12e4ac4eb3ea9421c420301a0c6460d9830d74a9df87efa4912010", "sha256:2e4ee3380d6de9c9ec04745830fd9e2eccb3e6cf790d39d7b98ffd19b0dd754a", "sha256:3373d5d70a5fe74a2c1bb6d2cfd9609ecf686d47a2d7b1d37a8f3b6bf6003aea", "sha256:47711010ad8555514b434df65f7d7b076bb8261df1ca9bb78f53d3b2db02e95c", "sha256:4c66707fabe114439db9068ee468c26bbdf909cac0fb58686a42a24de1760c71", "sha256:50193e430acfc1346175fcbdaa28ffec49947a06918b7b92130744e81e640110", "sha256:52b8b60467cd7dd1e9ed082188b4e6bb35aa5cdd01777621a1658910745b90be", "sha256:60dedbb91afcbfdc9bc0b1f3f402804070deed7392c23eb7a7f07fa857868e8a", "sha256:62b8e4b1e28009ef2846b4c7852046736bab361f7aeadeb6a5b89ebec3c7055a", "sha256:666dbfb6ec68962c033a450943ded891bed2d54e6755e35e5835d63f4f6931d5", "sha256:675d61ffbfa78604709862923189bad94014bef562cc35cf61d3a07bba02a7ed", "sha256:679b0076f67ecc0138fd2ede3a8fd196dddc2ad3254069bcb9faf9a79b1cebcd", "sha256:7349ab0fa0c429c82442a27a9673fc802ffdb7c7775fad780226cb234965e53c", "sha256:7ab55401287bfec946ced39700c053796e7cc0e3acbef09993a9ad2adba6ca6e", "sha256:7e50d0a0cc3189f9cb0aeb3a6a6af18c16f59f004b866cd2be1c14b36134a4a0", "sha256:95a7476c59002f2f6c590b9b7b998306fba6a5aa646b1e22ddfeaf8f78c3a29c", "sha256:96ff0b2ad353d8f990b63294c8986f1ec3cb19d749234014f4e7eb0112ceba5a", "sha256:9fad7dcb1aac3c7f0584a5a8133e3a43eeb2fe127f47e3632d43d677c66c102b", "sha256:9ff0f4f29c51e2803569d7a51c2304de5554655a60c5d776e35b4a41413830d0", "sha256:a354325ee03388678242a4d7ebcd08b5c727033fcff3b2f536aea978e15ee9e6", "sha256:a4abb4f9001ad2858e7ac189089c42178fcce737e4169dc61321660f1a96c7d2", "sha256:ab47dbe5cc8210f55aa58e4805fe224dac469cde56b9f731a4c098b91917159a", "sha256:afedb719a9dcfc7eaf2287b839d8198e06dcd4cb5d276a3df279231138e83d30", "sha256:b3ce300f3644fb06443ee2222c2201dd3a89ea6040541412b8fa189341847218", "sha256:b97fe8060236edf3662adfc2c633f56a08ae30560c56310562cb4f95500022d5", "sha256:bfe25acf8b437eb2a8b2d49d443800a5f18508cd811fea3181723922a8a82b07", "sha256:cd25bcecc4974d09257ffcd1f098ee778f7834c3ad767fe5db785be9a4aa9cb2", "sha256:d209d8969599b27ad20994c8e41936ee0964e6da07478d6c35016bc386b66ad4", "sha256:d5241e0a80d808d70546c697135da2c613f30e28251ff8307eb72ba696945764", "sha256:edd8b5fe47dab091176d21bb6de568acdd906d1887a4584a15a9a96a1dca06ef", "sha256:f870204a840a60da0b12273ef34f7051e98c3b5961b61b0c2c1be6dfd64fbcd3", "sha256:ffa75af20b44f8dba823498024771d5ac50620e6915abac414251bd971b4529f" ], "index": "pypi", "markers": "python_version >= \'3.9\'", "version": "==1.26.4" }, "pillow": { "hashes": [ "sha256:0304004f8067386b477d20a518b50f3fa658a28d44e4116970abfcd94fac34a8", "sha256:0689b5a8c5288bc0504d9fcee48f61a6a586b9b98514d7d29b840143d6734f39", "sha256:0eae2073305f451d8ecacb5474997c08569fb4eb4ac231ffa4ad7d342fdc25ac", "sha256:0fb3e7fc88a14eacd303e90481ad983fd5b69c761e9e6ef94c983f91025da869", "sha256:11fa2e5984b949b0dd6d7a94d967743d87c577ff0b83392f17cb3990d0d2fd6e", "sha256:127cee571038f252a552760076407f9cff79761c3d436a12af6000cd182a9d04", "sha256:154e939c5f0053a383de4fd3d3da48d9427a7e985f58af8e94d0b3c9fcfcf4f9", "sha256:15587643b9e5eb26c48e49a7b33659790d28f190fc514a322d55da2fb5c2950e", "sha256:170aeb00224ab3dc54230c797f8404507240dd868cf52066f66a41b33169bdbe", "sha256:1b5e1b74d1bd1b78bc3477528919414874748dd363e6272efd5abf7654e68bef", "sha256:1da3b2703afd040cf65ec97efea81cfba59cdbed9c11d8efc5ab09df9509fc56", "sha256:1e23412b5c41e58cec602f1135c57dfcf15482013ce6e5f093a86db69646a5aa", "sha256:2247178effb34a77c11c0e8ac355c7a741ceca0a732b27bf11e747bbc950722f", "sha256:257d8788df5ca62c980314053197f4d46eefedf4e6175bc9412f14412ec4ea2f", "sha256:3031709084b6e7852d00479fd1d310b07d0ba82765f973b543c8af5061cf990e", "sha256:322209c642aabdd6207517e9739c704dc9f9db943015535783239022002f054a", "sha256:322bdf3c9b556e9ffb18f93462e5f749d3444ce081290352c6070d014c93feb2", "sha256:33870dc4653c5017bf4c8873e5488d8f8d5f8935e2f1fb9a2208c47cdd66efd2", "sha256:35bb52c37f256f662abdfa49d2dfa6ce5d93281d323a9af377a120e89a9eafb5", "sha256:3c31822339516fb3c82d03f30e22b1d038da87ef27b6a78c9549888f8ceda39a", "sha256:3eedd52442c0a5ff4f887fab0c1c0bb164d8635b32c894bc1faf4c618dd89df2", "sha256:3ff074fc97dd4e80543a3e91f69d58889baf2002b6be64347ea8cf5533188213", "sha256:47c0995fc4e7f79b5cfcab1fc437ff2890b770440f7696a3ba065ee0fd496563", "sha256:49d9ba1ed0ef3e061088cd1e7538a0759aab559e2e0a80a36f9fd9d8c0c21591", "sha256:51f1a1bffc50e2e9492e87d8e09a17c5eea8409cda8d3f277eb6edc82813c17c", "sha256:52a50aa3fb3acb9cf7213573ef55d31d6eca37f5709c69e6858fe3bc04a5c2a2", "sha256:54f1852cd531aa981bc0965b7d609f5f6cc8ce8c41b1139f6ed6b3c54ab82bfb", "sha256:609448742444d9290fd687940ac0b57fb35e6fd92bdb65386e08e99af60bf757", "sha256:69ffdd6120a4737710a9eee73e1d2e37db89b620f702754b8f6e62594471dee0", "sha256:6fad5ff2f13d69b7e74ce5b4ecd12cc0ec530fcee76356cac6742785ff71c452", "sha256:7049e301399273a0136ff39b84c3678e314f2158f50f517bc50285fb5ec847ad", "sha256:70c61d4c475835a19b3a5aa42492409878bbca7438554a1f89d20d58a7c75c01", "sha256:716d30ed977be8b37d3ef185fecb9e5a1d62d110dfbdcd1e2a122ab46fddb03f", "sha256:753cd8f2086b2b80180d9b3010dd4ed147efc167c90d3bf593fe2af21265e5a5", "sha256:773efe0603db30c281521a7c0214cad7836c03b8ccff897beae9b47c0b657d61", "sha256:7823bdd049099efa16e4246bdf15e5a13dbb18a51b68fa06d6c1d4d8b99a796e", "sha256:7c8f97e8e7a9009bcacbe3766a36175056c12f9a44e6e6f2d5caad06dcfbf03b", "sha256:823ef7a27cf86df6597fa0671066c1b596f69eba53efa3d1e1cb8b30f3533068", "sha256:8373c6c251f7ef8bda6675dd6d2b3a0fcc31edf1201266b5cf608b62a37407f9", "sha256:83b2021f2ade7d1ed556bc50a399127d7fb245e725aa0113ebd05cfe88aaf588", "sha256:870ea1ada0899fd0b79643990809323b389d4d1d46c192f97342eeb6ee0b8483", "sha256:8d12251f02d69d8310b046e82572ed486685c38f02176bd08baf216746eb947f", "sha256:9c23f307202661071d94b5e384e1e1dc7dfb972a28a2310e4ee16103e66ddb67", "sha256:9d189550615b4948f45252d7f005e53c2040cea1af5b60d6f79491a6e147eef7", "sha256:a086c2af425c5f62a65e12fbf385f7c9fcb8f107d0849dba5839461a129cf311", "sha256:a2b56ba36e05f973d450582fb015594aaa78834fefe8dfb8fcd79b93e64ba4c6", "sha256:aebb6044806f2e16ecc07b2a2637ee1ef67a11840a66752751714a0d924adf72", "sha256:b1b3020d90c2d8e1dae29cf3ce54f8094f7938460fb5ce8bc5c01450b01fbaf6", "sha256:b4b6b1e20608493548b1f32bce8cca185bf0480983890403d3b8753e44077129", "sha256:b6f491cdf80ae540738859d9766783e3b3c8e5bd37f5dfa0b76abdecc5081f13", "sha256:b792a349405fbc0163190fde0dc7b3fef3c9268292586cf5645598b48e63dc67", "sha256:b7c2286c23cd350b80d2fc9d424fc797575fb16f854b831d16fd47ceec078f2c", "sha256:babf5acfede515f176833ed6028754cbcd0d206f7f614ea3447d67c33be12516", "sha256:c365fd1703040de1ec284b176d6af5abe21b427cb3a5ff68e0759e1e313a5e7e", "sha256:c4225f5220f46b2fde568c74fca27ae9771536c2e29d7c04f4fb62c83275ac4e", "sha256:c570f24be1e468e3f0ce7ef56a89a60f0e05b30a3669a459e419c6eac2c35364", "sha256:c6dafac9e0f2b3c78df97e79af707cdc5ef8e88208d686a4847bab8266870023", "sha256:c8de2789052ed501dd829e9cae8d3dcce7acb4777ea4a479c14521c942d395b1", "sha256:cb28c753fd5eb3dd859b4ee95de66cc62af91bcff5db5f2571d32a520baf1f04", "sha256:cb4c38abeef13c61d6916f264d4845fab99d7b711be96c326b84df9e3e0ff62d", "sha256:d1b35bcd6c5543b9cb547dee3150c93008f8dd0f1fef78fc0cd2b141c5baf58a", "sha256:d8e6aeb9201e655354b3ad049cb77d19813ad4ece0df1249d3c793de3774f8c7", "sha256:d8ecd059fdaf60c1963c58ceb8997b32e9dc1b911f5da5307aab614f1ce5c2fb", "sha256:da2b52b37dad6d9ec64e653637a096905b258d2fc2b984c41ae7d08b938a67e4", "sha256:e87f0b2c78157e12d7686b27d63c070fd65d994e8ddae6f328e0dcf4a0cd007e", "sha256:edca80cbfb2b68d7b56930b84a0e45ae1694aeba0541f798e908a49d66b837f1", "sha256:f379abd2f1e3dddb2b61bc67977a6b5a0a3f7485538bcc6f39ec76163891ee48", "sha256:fe4c15f6c9285dc54ce6553a3ce908ed37c8f3825b5a51a15c91442bb955b868" ], "index": "pypi", "markers": "python_version >= \'3.8\'", "version": "==10.2.0" } }, "develop": {} }'

How do I unstring parsed_content to convert it to a nested dictionary? Manually, I can cut and paste the section within the ' ' symbols into a Python idle and it will immediately recognize it as a nested dictionary. Yet, how can this procedure be done via programming.

I think it's just JSON:
import json

with open("Pipfile.lock") as f:
   content = json.load(f)

